# Com DLL Gives Exception .NET 4 only

Tags: .net, com-interop

A COM DLL works in .NET 3.5 SP1, but gives exception in .NET 4.0

The full error is

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B229C879-1B52-4DE9-A42B-75C415EA1EBC} failed due to the following error: 8007045a A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A).

If I change the target framework to 3.5 it works, back to 4.0 it doesn't.

The application is a desktop WPF app.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Want to upgrade that comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DllMain() method of the DLL returned FALSE. You'll need to use a debugger to find out why.  Set a breakpoint on it and enable unmanaged debugging with Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Source code and a .pdb file for the DLL is required.